# Cake\Controller\Controller::set(string $var, mixed $value)

Tags: cakephp

`Cake\Controller\Controller::set(string $var, mixed $value)` is mentioned in the `cakePHP 3.5` Red Velvet cookbook as the way to set View variables. It works as advertised I am happy to say.

In which `cakePHP` source file is `Controller::set()` method implemented?

A search for `Controller::set(`) in the `cakePHP 3.5` Red Velvet API reveals nothing. `C:\cake\myProject\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\controller.php` reveals nothing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [a trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) used by the controller https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.View.ViewVarsTrait.html